# Showing that a function defines a probability distribution over a sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Omega_n = \{0, 1\}^n$, $s = X_1X_2\dots X_n$ a binary string of length $n$ with $X_i \in \{0, 1\}$ and $k(s) = \sum_{i = 1}^nX_i$. Let $p \in (0, 1)$, and define $\Pr(s) = p^{k(s)}(1 - p)^{n - k(s)}$. I want to show that the defined function $\Pr$ defines a probability distribution over $\Omega$, i.e. $\sum_{s \in \Omega} \Pr(s) = 1$, and $\forall s \in \Omega: \Pr(s) \geq 0$. The second property is trivially true as both terms in the product $p^{k(s)}(1 - p)^{n - k(s)}$ are non-negative. However the first property seems trickier. We can surely expand the sum with the help of the binomial theorem, $$\sum_{s \in \Omega} \Pr(s) = \sum_{s \in \Omega}p^{k(s)}(1 - p)^{n - k(s)} = \sum_{s \in \Omega} p^{k(s)} \sum_{i = 0}^{n - k(s)}{n - k(s) \choose i}(-p)^i,$$ but how can we argue that the sum equals one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{s\in\Omega}p^{k(s)}(1-p)^{n-k(s)}=(1-p)^n\sum_{s\in\Omega}\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^{k(s)}$$  Since there are $\binom nk$ bit strings with $k$ one bits we have
$$\begin{align}
(1-p)^n\sum_{s\in\Omega}\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^{k(s)}&=(1-p)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^k\\
&=(1-p)^n\left(1+\frac p{1-p}\right)^n\\
&=(1-p+p)^n=1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k=0,1,2,\dots, n$ let $\Omega_k:=\{s\in\{0,1\}^n\mid k(s)=k\}$.

Then $|\Omega_k|=\binom{n}k$ so that: $$\sum_{s\in\Omega}\Pr(s)=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{s\in\Omega_k}\Pr(s)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(p+(1-p))^n=1^n=1$$